# EF code-first migration: SqlCeException altering NTEXT column

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-ce, entity-framework-5

My application uses Entity Framework 5.0 code-first on top of a Sql CE database. Until now, we have used Automatic Migrations to manage entity mapping changes. However, I now have a change for which I need to create a custom migration to ensure no data is lost during the update. I made my changes to the entities, and used the Add-Migration command which generated Up() and Down() methods for me. I customized the Up() method to insert my custom sql to preserve the data, and tested my application.

When I run the application, I received the error:

> Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic migration. Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable automatic migration.

Ok, I don't understand this because all of my changes are detailed in the Up() method that got executed.
So I turn Automatic Migrations back on just to see what happens. Now I receive this error:

> "Cannot alter column of type NTEXT or IMAGE [ Column Name = LastName ]"

This error comes from a table/entity that hasn't even been touched with my changes. The existing database has this string mapped to **nvarchar(4000**). If I examine the DB after I receive this exception, I observe that the columns have been changed to **ntext**. What is EF doing? Why is it touching tables that haven't been changed? How can I get more information on what is going on here?

**Update:**
As a workaround, I attempted to mark each and every string type in my entities with a data annotation as such:

```
[Column(TypeName = "ntext")]
public virtual string LastName
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Now all of my strings are using ntext in the database. This leads to further exceptions when queries are performed:

> The ntext and image data types cannot be used in WHERE, HAVING, GROUP BY, ON, or IN clauses, except when these data types are used with the LIKE or IS NULL predicates.

So, to summarize:

1. Turning off automatic migrations causes EF to detect phantom changes and throw exceptions
2. Turning on automatic migration in conjunction with a custom migration causes all existing strings to be mapped to ntext
3. strings mapped to ntext cannot be queried, effectively making them useless in my application

Answer (score 0):

For me, a modification of an `Up` method worked out.

```
SerialNumber = c.String(maxLength: 99)
```

was applied instead of

```
SerialNumber = c.String()
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue and i fixed by editing the table column data type manually by opening SQl Server Compact/SQlite Toolbox explorer windows, and then expend the database name, then expend the table you want to edit and right click the column you want to edit, and click drop script, then run the scrip and the column will be dropped from the table, then right click the table and click add column and from here you can choose what data type you want and add the new column that way.  I hope this helps some one.